# strtok and reading from several functions

Tags: c, string, char

```
    int main () {
    char *results = NULL;        
    char line[]   =   "a,b,c"; 
    const char delim[] = ",";

    // First token
    results = strtok(line, delim);

    if (strcmp(results, "a") == 0)
    { OtherFunction(line); }
    }

    void OtherFunction(char* line)
    {

       results = strtok(line, delim);

       // Read through
       while(results != NULL ) 
       {
          printf(" %s\n", results);

          results = strtok(NULL, delim);
       }
    }
```

**Why I am not getting the b and c in the other function but if I do the same thing in the original it works?**

Comment: How is results declared?

Comment: You're going wrong with the **strtok()** usage. Inside the `OtherFunction` you'll need to write `results = strtok(NULL, delim);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok()` is a horrible abomination. It's not thread-safe, re-entrant or any of the good things, it keeps state (it remembers where it last read from) **and it modifies the string it operates on**!
 `strtok()` replaces the delimiters you specify with `'\0'` in the string. When you call `strtok(line, delim)` the second time (in `OtherFunction()`), the string is already null-terminated after the `a`.

 Also, using `strtok()` on a string literal is not allowed because of the change it causes.

Comment: Thus, you recommend coding my own function?

Comment: @SpcCode: Well, there is `strtok_r()`, which is more sane.

Comment: @SpcCode Belay that, `strtok_r()` has the same problems for your case: It also inserts '\0', and thus should not be used on string literals...

Comment: Guys, any alternative/choice?

Comment: I've looked at this in the past and ended up writing my own function, but it was using hard-coded delimiters, so it wouldn't be of much use in general. I'd advise searching for "alternatives to strtok()" || asking a new question for it.